# Upgraded to 20.04, too slow boot up

Tags: boot, 20.04

Ubuntu Version: **20.04** 
DiskType: **HDD**

```
Startup finished in 5.137s (firmware) + 3.525s (loader) + 4.109s (kernel) + 1min 13.665s (userspace) = 1min 26.438s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 12.518s in userspace
```

```
42.842s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                             >
22.628s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                     >
21.565s udisks2.service                                                        >
18.962s snapd.service                                                          >
18.125s postgresql@11-main.service                                             >
18.018s postgresql@12-main.service                                             >
15.183s systemd-journal-flush.service                                          >
11.914s networkd-dispatcher.service                                            >
11.435s postfix@-.service                                                      >
10.914s dev-sda1.device                                                        >
 9.903s accounts-daemon.service                                                >
 8.082s apport-autoreport.service                                              >
 7.637s teamviewerd.service                                                    >
 7.254s polkit.service                                                         >
 6.908s NetworkManager.service                                                 >
 6.889s avahi-daemon.service                                                   >
 6.885s bluetooth.service                                                      >
 6.517s switcheroo-control.service                                             >
 6.511s thermald.service                                                       >
 6.509s systemd-logind.service                                                 >
 6.508s wpa_supplicant.service                                                 >
 6.245s dev-loop6.device                                                       >
 6.073s dev-loop8.device
```

Output from Critical Chain

```
graphical.target @1min 12.518s
└─multi-user.target @1min 12.518s
  └─postfix.service @1min 3.835s +5ms
    └─postfix@-.service @52.394s +11.435s
      └─network-online.target @52.204s
        └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @29.574s +22.628s
          └─NetworkManager.service @22.659s +6.908s
            └─dbus.service @22.656s
              └─basic.target @22.625s
                └─sockets.target @22.625s
                  └─snapd.socket @22.624s +773us
                    └─sysinit.target @22.421s
                      └─systemd-timesyncd.service @22.023s +397ms
                        └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @20.116s +1.777s
                          └─local-fs.target @20.112s
                            └─home-xpt1x-data.mount @16.307s +3.805s
                              └─dev-sda5.device @16.275s
```

A thing i noticed too, is that manufacturer's logo appear first for about 6-7 secs then, manufacturer's logo again appears with Ubuntu logo in bottom appears with loading spinner, even after than it takes too much time to reach the main screen.
I see some services are taking too long, please suggest solution ..

Comment: Is this the first time you started your device right after the upgrade? Or have you used the upgrade before and are booting another time?

Comment: Another time, i did upgrade yesterday, booted too many times after that

Comment: How long is it taking? I get around 1 minute on an HDD

Comment: Read your output: Your MTA, postfix, looks like most of the problem. It takes 11 seconds to start. Postfix requires network connection, so the system waits 22 more seconds for the network to come up.

Comment: @CStafford-14 i just edited my post, check at the top of the post about time

Comment: @user535733, so what should i do to fix it ?

Comment: Well, first, ask yourself why you are running an MTA. Do you use it?

Comment: What is an MTA ?

Comment: Look it up. Ask yourself why you installed postfix. It was not part of your original install. You installed it. Why? Is whatever that reason was still valid?

Comment: Is it a part of any mail client coz once i was trying out mail clients, maybe it got in from there and i also dont need postgres should i disable it too ?

Comment: Postgres was also not part of the original install. If you're not using it, get rid of it.

Comment: An MTA is not part of a mail client. Removing it won't harm your Ubuntu system.